# Firebase Google login not staying persistence

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-native-firebase

I am developing an application, with an feature of `Google Login` through `Firebase`. I am trying to login via Google with the help of an library, known as `react-native-google-signin`. It is well known library in the field of ReactNative for Google Login.

My problem is not with this library, but the problem is that while I am using `react-native-google-signin` library with firebase to login via google. Firebase User is not staying persistence, I mean to say that when I am opening app after close `FirebaseUser` is getting `null`. Below the code I am using to login via firebase,

```
GoogleSignin.signIn().then(data => { 
const credentials = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(data.idToken, data.accessToken);

firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL)
.then() => { 

    return firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credentials);
}).catch(error => {

    console.log('Error', error);
})

}).then(user => {

   console.log('user', firebase.auth().currentUser);
}).catch(error => {

   console.log('Error', error);
})
```

I also checked Firebase Docs, tried by using `setPersistence()` method but still I am getting `null` user after open app again.

Comment: You are probably not using `onAuthStateChanged` listener to detect initial auth state. That is the right way to detect if a user is signed in or not on initial app launch.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

when you first time open your app you get `user` null, but after login one time then reopen your app and you will get previously logged in user in your console

```
async _setupGoogleSignin() {
try {
  await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices({ autoResolve: true });
  await GoogleSignin.configure({
    webClientId: 'YOUR WEBCLIENTID',
    offlineAccess: false
  });
  const user = await GoogleSignin.currentUserAsync();
  console.log("user",user); // HERE YOU GET LOGGED IN USER IN YOUR CONSOLE FIRST TIME IT WILL BE NULL BUT AFTER YOU GET PREVIOUSLY LOGGED IN USER
  this.setState({user});
}
catch(err) {
  console.log("Play services error", err.code, err.message);
}}
```

then

```
_signIn() {
GoogleSignin.signIn()
.then((user) => {
  console.log(user);
  this.setState({user: user});
  const credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(user.idToken, user.accessToken);
  // console.log(credential);
  return firebase.auth().signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(credential);
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.log('WRONG SIGNIN', err);
})
.done();}
```

it is worked for me...
hope it will help you...

Comment: so, where does the GoogleSignIn api used here store the login information. How does it know and get the previous login details when the app is re-launched (after being terminated earlier)